# Word spacing in LaTeX

Tags: spacing

How to implement word spacing in LaTeX? For websites this is done with [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp):

```css
word-spacing: 0.5em;
```

---

This is for reference about other tags

- paper: custom
- layout:
- layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
- modes:
- h-part:(L,W,R)=(0.0pt, 72.26999pt, 0.0pt)
- v-part:(T,H,B)=(0.0pt, 72.26999pt, 0.0pt)
- `\paperwidth`=72.26999pt
- `\paperheight`=72.26999pt
- `\textwidth`=72.26999pt
- `\textheight`=72.26999pt
- `\oddsidemargin`=-72.26999pt
- `\evensidemargin`=-72.26999pt
- `\topmargin`=-109.26999pt

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense: TeX and friends justify text by default. This means that that word spacing varies from word to word...

Comment: I agree with @Seamus, this is normally not done with LaTeX which is for larger/real documents. However, I like the technical aspect of the question.

Comment: I recently learned about the existence of `\spaceskip` (used e.g. by `ragged2e`), which seem related, but I'm not sure at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other answers have pointed to `\spaceskip`: I think an example might be useful. In the first paragraph, TeX is using the usual justified approach. In paragraph two, I've set up to use a ragged-right margin in much the same way as `ragged2e` does. This uses the interword space taken from the font. In the third paragraph, I've explicitly set the interword space to 0.5 em (the other ragged-right parameters continue to apply).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\parfillskip 0 pt plus 1 fil\relax
\leftskip    0 pt           \relax
\rightskip   0 pt plus 2 em \relax
\spaceskip \fontdimen 2 \font
\lipsum[1]

\spaceskip   0.5 em         \relax
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

In TeX the spacing between words is ruled by parameters coming from the current font and usually they are adjusted so as to provide a good typographical result.

The default fonts use a word spacing of M/3 (one third of an em), which can be stretched without adding much to the line badness up to M/2 or shrinked up to 2/9 of an em.

The Times font in the TeX distributions uses an interword space of M/4 stretchable to 4/10 of an em and shrinkable to M/5.

There is a parameter called `\spaceskip`, but it should be used with care. You find details about it in the TeXbook or in TeX by Topic (the latter should be in your TeX distribution).

Answer (score 7):

While I agree with Seamus and Martin, word spacing can be adjusted if you really need/want to (in titles or page headers for example).

In PDFTex, you can use the `microtype` package for that, with the `\textls` command:

```
\textls[100]{Spaced text}
\textls[-50]{Compacted text}
```

You can do finer things with XeTeX by using the `fontspec` package to select a font:

```
\newfontfamily\headerfont[LetterSpace=12,WordSpace=2,Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}
```

Note that I strongly recommend deactivating ligatures (hence the `Ligatures=NoCommon`) to prevent uneven spacing of ligatures if you use `LetterSpace`.

Comment: Word spacing is not letter spacing.

Comment: Right @egreg. `\textls` is mostly about letter spacing, but `WordSpace` is about word spacing. In most of the cases where I've had to play with word spacing (headers, etc.), I've had to adjust letter spacing, too.